# Are there unfalsifiable statements that, in the end, turn out to be true?

Tags: epistemology, popper, falsifiability

changing a little bit the famous black swan example to:

```
not all swans are white
```

it seems to be unfalsifiable, but in the end (when we discovered australia), it turned out to be true.

Comment: Is not this statement unprovable but falsifiable, as demonstrated?

Comment: If statement A is unfalsifiable, then "not A" is too. Then unless A is non sense ("dichotomy is more to the left than the color blue") either A or not A has to be true.

Comment: All black swans are black. Unfalsifiable. Also true. Analytic statements are not falsifiable, ie mathematical statements - accept premises, accept conclusions, QED.

Comment: tautologies cannot be shown to be false, yet are true

Comment: thanks for your comments @CriglCragl and Dave, but I don't see why "not all swans are white" would be an analytic statement nor a tautology. could you please elaborate it?

Comment: You are mixing up logical proof and empirical testing.  If you clear that up you will have a sensible question.

Comment: *black* swans are black. It's a definition, an assertion

Answer (score 1):

This is where Ibn Sina's insight that logic should be temporalised would prove its value. As well as the epistemology that underlies it.

We should say, a certain statement is unfalsifiable *now* and in the forseeable future *given* what we now know.

Comment: To say something is falsifiable is to say it could be falsified at some point in the future. So, to say something is unfalsifiable "now" is to say it is unfalsifiable at every point in the future as well. Because, if it were falsifiable at some time t in the future, then it could be falsified at some time t2 in the future of t. But t2 is in the future of the current time, meaning it is falsifiable "now" as well.

Comment: @causative: Ibn Sina's temporalisation of logic is a lot more sophisticated than I have given above. I'm merely giving the gist of it so the idea can be understood. Constructivists, for example, would have no truck with how you define falsifiable as we do not know what we do not know.

Comment: What does knowing have to do with it? Whether something is falsifiable is independent of whether we know it is falsifiable.

Comment: @causative: Really? If you falsify something, then you know how to falsify it. Look up modal logic.

Comment: Yes, if you actually *falsify* it, you knew how. But it was *falsifiable* even before you knew specifically how. Falsifiable simply means "possible to be falsified." We are not aware of all possibilities, but that doesn't stop them from being possibilities.

Comment: @causative Maybe something is not a 'possibility' until someone recognizes that it is? So far as I know, nothing else in the universe knows what 'possible' means. Same goes for falsifiable, etc...

Comment: @ScottRowe But in common usage, we often speak of things being possible before we know exactly how to do them. "It's possible to build a bridge across this river." Yet nobody knows exactly *how* to build the bridge until the design for the bridge has been completed. We would still say it is possible, before finishing the design, because bridges have been built across many similar rivers.

Comment: @ScottRowe We also ask "Is it possible?" for something that we're not sure about. This question would not make any sense if only things known to be possible are possible (because the answer to the question would always be "no, it's not possible" under that interpretation, because it was not yet known to be possible when the question was asked). The question implies that possibility is some fact of the world which humans can investigate and be unsure or not know about.

Comment: @causative: Look up constructive logic and whether they think the Riemann hypothesis is true or false? They say it is niether of these options. In which case, is it falsifiable? Or what about the continuum hypothesis?

Comment: @MoziburUllah Can you cite any mathematician studying constructive logic who thinks the Riemann hypothesis is neither true nor false? To my understanding, constructivism in mathematics still says that unproven propositions can be true. It sounds like you are interpreting the absence of the law of excluded middle in a strange way. Or maybe you meant to say the continuum hypothesis rather than the Riemann hypothesis.

Comment: @causative: I meant both. Have a look for Brouwerian counter-example at the SEP entry for constructive mathematics. They use the explicit example of the Goldmann Conjecture but they also mention it applies just as well for the Riemann hypothesis.

Comment: @causative: To help you along, [here](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mathematics-constructive/) is the article in question. And that should be Goldbach above.

Comment: @causative: Constructivism is not about saying unproven statements can be true  thats the classical position. The constructivist position is that the truth should be demonstrated by an actual construction. Hence the name, constructivism. Non-constructive proofs are therefore disallowed.

Comment: @MoziburUllah The quote is: "An example of this type, showing that a constructive proof of some classical result P would enable us to solve the Goldbach conjecture (and, by similar arguments, many other hitherto open problems, such as the Riemann hypothesis), is called a Brouwerian example for, or even a Brouwerian counterexample to, the statement P." This does not say what you claimed. It's a "Brouwerian counterexample" to P, not to the Goldbach conjecture; and it does not say that statements with a Brouwerian counterexample aren't true or false.

Comment: @MoziburUllah You've misunderstood constructivism. Constructivists say that the truth should be demonstrated by an actual construction, yes; but I have not seen any of them claim that there is no truth until a construction is found. It is simply a question of which kinds of proofs they accept, not a question of the truth status of propositions prior to being proved.

Comment: Yes, sure. I glanced at it, rather than reading it properly. But my main contention stands: look at tge two comments above. In constructivism, it's not enough to claim a statement is true or false, you have to *construct* an example showing its proof or disproof. There is no such construction for the Riemann hypothesis. So it hangs in some netherworld between falsity and truth.

Comment: No, what I've claimed is a position within constructivism.

Comment: @causative When you said: "*We are not aware of all possibilities, but that doesn't stop them from being possibilities.*" I was saying that from my understanding, something can only be called 'possible' when a human conceives of it being possible. We can't reason about things we have never thought of. An ant or a sunflower don't know 'possible'. The world just does what it does, without any alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

1.) The claim

> not all swans are white

has been verified. Hence the claim is not falsifiable.

2.) The point of Popper's falsificationism is the falsification of the claim

> all swans are white

The latter claim has been derived from induction. Popper used this counter-example to show that general statements cannot be derived from induction.

3.) Falsfication and verification are not symmetric: A statement of the form "There exists ..." can be verified, a statement of the form "For all ..." can be falsified. The statement from part 1) is equivalent to "There exists a non-white swan" and can verified - and has been verified indeed.

**Changed** part 1) after the OP simplified the question. I deleted also my corresponding comments.

Comment: "Not all swans are white" can be verified, but that has no bearing on whether it can be *falsified*, which is OP's point. There is no set of swans we could observe - even in a hypothetical universe in which "not all swans are white" is false - that would falsify the statement, "not all swans are white."

Comment: Well, that's debatable. Anyway, your comment here is agreeing with the OP and contradicting your own answer; you are agreeing that "not all swans are white" cannot be falsified. And yet it is true.

Comment: thanks for answering @JoWehler ... but why do you think both "not all swans are white" and "there exists at least one non-white swan" statements (which I agree to be equivalent) are falsifiable?

to falsify them, you need to be able to demonstrate that all swans are white, right? but this doesn't look feasible.

let's suppose you don't know the existence of black swans in australia, you go to the closest park and all swans are white. then I tell you, this doesn't demonstrate that all swans are white, go to the next neighborhood, and so on...

Comment: btw... I know the original statement is "all swans are white", and that one is falsifiable. I just wanted to see what happens with falsifiability when we change the claim the other way around.

Comment: @JoWehler Your own answer says, "Hence your example does not support the existence of 'unfalsifiable statements that, in the end, turn out to be true'." But you are claiming in the comment that the statement OP gave is unfalsifiable (because it is verifiable) and of course it is true. So that does make it an example of an unfalsifiable statement that turned out to be true.

Comment: “Hence the claim is not falsifiable.” But “not all swans are white “ is indeed falsifiable. The claim has been resolved, to be sure. But the original claim, as it is stated, remains falsifiable.

Comment: @MarkAndrews why do you think the claim "not all swans are white" are falsifiable? could you elaborate it? in the following comment I have explained why I think it is unfalsifiable: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/90400/are-there-unfalsifiable-statements-that-in-the-end-turn-out-to-be-true#comment253000_90401

Comment: @csfb. “Not all swans are white” is falsifiable because, to show the statement is wrong, someone remains free to prove that based on swan DNA (for example) it is impossible for the bird to be anything but white.  This is not a claim like, “Two days ago I saw a non-white swan” or “In the spiritual realm, no swans are white.” Both these statements are truly unfalsifiable.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why there's a *falsifiability criterion* in re scientific claims is they *can't be* verified. For example, you *can't say* the theory of relativity is *true* - it's just a *model* that (only) *fits* observation i.e. it *hasn't been* falsified.